# Given triangle ABC find P along BC such that AP is perpendicular to BC using proyection and dot product

Tags: geometry, multivariable-calculus, vectors

$A=(1,1), B=(2,3)$ and $C =(3,-1).$

$\vec{AP}\perp \vec{BC}$

We have that $P = c(BC)$, then:
$(cBC-A)\cdot BC=0$

$cBC\cdot BC-A\cdot BC=0$
$c=\frac{A\cdot BC}{BC\cdot BC}=-\frac{3}{17}$

My result is $P=-\frac{3}{17}(1,-4)$
but the correct answer is 
$\frac{1}{17}(41,23)$

[Graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G74Jk.png)

Comment: Your assumption that P=c(BC) is not true as P is line joining origin and P, which may not be parallel to BC. What is true is that PB = c(BC). Draw a figure to convince yourself

Comment: Done, thanks! It would be true if both vectors started at the origin, can the definition be extended to this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [section formula](https://brilliant.org/wiki/section-formula/), we have $P = (2+\lambda,3-4\lambda)$, where $0\le\lambda\le1$. Consequently, $\vec {BP} = \langle \lambda, -4\lambda \rangle$, and $\vec {AP} = \langle 1+\lambda, 2-4\lambda \rangle$. Since $\vec{BP}\cdot\vec{AP}=0$, we have $$\lambda(1+\lambda)-4\lambda(2-4\lambda)=0 \implies \lambda(17\lambda-7)=0.$$
Consequently, $\lambda=\frac{7}{17}$ and $P = (2+\lambda,3-4\lambda)=(41/17,23/17)$.

Comment: Thank you, it was a resourceful solution than the one using dot product and proyection definition, thus learned more than i expected.

Answer (score 0):

$\vec{AP}\perp \vec{BC}$

$\vec{BP}$ is the proyection of $\vec{BA}$ along $\vec{BC}$

By $c\vec{BC}=\frac{\vec{BA}\cdot \vec{BC}}{\vec{BC}\cdot \vec{BC}}\vec{BC}$

$\vec{BP}=(\frac{7}{17},-\frac{28}{17})$

$P=\vec{BP}+B=(\frac{41}{17},\frac{23}{17})$